# Referencing Children elements in JQUERY Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a little chat panel to practice what I am learning with JQuery.

So far I have managed to create an ugly panel that allows users to enter a message and send it to the left side of the panel.

But the messaged appear on top of each other. So I am using Jquery to animate the messages sent which push them upwards.

I have a function called animateLeftSide which attempts to move each element created up. But currently it moves ALL of them up. How do i target each element individually?

Here is the function I've written:

```
var animateLeftSide = function() {
    var numberOfMessages = $('.leftside').children().length
    var i = 0
    while (i < numberOfMessages) {
        if (i > 0) {
            $('.leftside').children(i).animate({
                    top: '-=70px'
                }, 100) //move it upwards 
        }
        i++;
    }
};
```

[Here is a DEMO of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/5e25kqac/2/).

Answer (score 1):

It simply makes all of your elements move up because you are moving all of your elements up each and every time the input is entered (using while loop). Just remove the while loop. But removing it, will leave a blank space for the first time when we insert. For that, I have modified your js in your jsfiddle and found it working. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i=false;
    $('#btn-send').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=textbox]').val();

        if (toAdd.length == 0) {
            alert("No message Entered");
        } else {

            animateLeftSide(i);
            i=true;

            $('.leftside').append('<div class="message">' + toAdd + '</div>');
            $('input[name=textbox]').val('');
            //alert("" + $('.leftside').children().length + "");
                    }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.message', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });


    var animateLeftSide = function (i) {  
        if(i){
                $('.leftside').children().animate({
                    top: '-=70px'
                }, 100) //move it upwards 
        }
    };

});
```

If you are still not clear, just leave a comment. I may clear you.